# how to call a div inside jquery switch statement

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to be able to call the canvas by Id depending on the button clicked on the mouse,am using a switch statement to read what button as been clicked , how can i archive  that with this switch statement

am making a clickable map,one which when someone clicks on a province it shows a graph of the population difference by age and gender, so  this canvas are holding that the graphs , so how do i make the click on the map pop up a graph of that particular province, am using an svg image

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<canvas id="myBar"   width="400" height="400"></canvas>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function()
              {

    $('#map g').mousedown(function(event) {
switch (event.which) {
    case 1:
        document.getElementById('myBar').addEventListener('click',         function());
        break;
    case 2:
        alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');

        break;
    case 3:
          document.getElementById('myChart').addEventListener('click',         function());
        break;
    default:
        alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
}
 });                
              });

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "Call the canvas?". What should happen when a button is clicked? Because now you add event listeners that don't do anything

Comment: hi Hugo Delsing ,i want when i click the left or right mouse buttons they need to call a particular canavs by id.

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is the code in jQuery:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<canvas id="myBar"   width="400" height="400"></canvas>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#map g').mousedown(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          switch (event.which) {
            case 1: $("#myBar").on('click', function(){
                                               //what you need to do
                                             });
            break;
            case 2: alert('Middle Mouse button pressed.');
            break;
            case 3:$("#myChart").on('click', function(){
                                                //what you need to do
                                             });
            break;
            default: alert('You have a strange Mouse!');
            break;
          }
      });                
   });
</script>
```

You also want to use [event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), to avoid the click event to do the default option (sub menu)

Comment: am making a clickable map,one which when someone clicks on a province it shows a graph of the population difference by age and gender, so  this canvas are holding that the graphs , so how do i make the click on the map pop up a graph of that particular province, am using an svg image

Comment: are the `graph canvas` generated from a DB, ajax call or something like that or are static DOM elements? could you add some of that code to the question?

Comment: OK, then inside the function that calls the on click event, you should make the call to the DB (probably an Ajax call) and return the data to later load it into the display div. each case in the switch statement will make a different Ajax call as required. without some more code or explanation of what you are trying to achieve, I will be only imagining how I could implement your task...